# Example of non-local operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $T: C_{0}^{\infty}(R^{n}) \to C^{\infty}(R^{n})$ be a linear operator. $T$ is local if $$\operatorname{supp}  (Tu) \subset \operatorname{supp} (u),$$ for all $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}({R}^{n})$. We know all differential operators are local. But what is an example of non local operator?

Answer (score 1):

For example 
$$ u \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R^n} u \, dx \cdot 1_{\mathbb R^n} $$
is a linear operator, which is non-local.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that this fact leads to the [fractional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) being non-local.

Comment: @martini Do you mean characteristic function by your "$1_{R^{n}}$"?

Comment: Yes, the constant function $1_{\mathbb R^n}\colon x \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Thanks you so much! But why do we need to multiply by $1_{R^{n}}$?

Comment: @curiousm Just because you want $C^\infty_0 \to C^\infty$, but not $C_0^\infty \to \mathbb R$.